I upgraded an extension and now I get this error(see screen shot), How do I Fix this?
[![error page joomla error page (membershipType::Get) ][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/p4IY1Qfg.png error page joomle error (membershipType::Get)

Which extension did you upgrade?  What version of Civi are you using?  Do you have the Membership component enabled?

I believe I added the one for deceased people. It said something about opting people out didn't think that meant me too. The newest stable version. 5.7x.xx. yes I believe I have it activated

Ok, are there error messages in the logfile?

fixed, I am going to try to build more today

Good that you have fixed it.  Please add an answer below to help others hitting similar problems.

the extension was just disabled issue. is still persisting Needs API's??
